# Updated the wordpress 4.4 error yoast plugin in script

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have update the `WordPress` and theme i am having error in the `yoast script`. Need help!

I am get `yoast-seo-307.min.js?ver=3.0.7:1`

[image]

What i want to do

Comment: Check to see if yoast has an upadate. I'm running (free) yoast and 4.4 and it's all working for me.

Comment: Yoast is up to date.

Comment: Might be a theme conflict then. Try with the default wordpress theme.

Comment: @Joshua Thank you.But its live site.I tried activating and deactivating yoast still pages is sometime not responding.